# How to select items on table based on 3 relations?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 3 tables:

```
 Categories
 | id | name
 | 1  | Samsung
 | 2  | Apple


 Products
 | id | category_id | name
 | 1  | 1           | Galaxy S4
 | 2  | 1           | Galaxy S3
 | 3  | 1           | SHG-G600
 | 4  | 3           | Lumia 920


 Tags
 | id | product_id | name         | type
 | 1  | 1          | smart-phone  | phoneType
 | 2  | 2          | smart-phone  | phoneType
 | 3  | 3          | normal-cell  | phoneType
 | 4  | 1          | red          | phoneColor
```

I'm trying to find a way to select all Samsung devices which have 'smart-phone' as 'phoneType' and 'red' as 'phoneColor'.

So this what I did until now:

```sql
 SELECT *
 FROM `products`
 INNER JOIN `product_tag` ON `product_tag`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
 INNER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `products`.`id`
 WHERE (
      `tags`.`type` = 'phoneType'
      AND `tags`.`name` = 'smart-phone'
      )
 OR (
      `tags`.`type` = 'phoneColor'
      AND `tags`.`name` = 'red'
      )     
 )
```

This did not work as is (without selecting category).

I also didn't know how to join categories and add `where categories.id = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting the logic in the `having` clause.  For your example code:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `products` p join
     `product_tag` pt
     ON pt.`product_id` = p.`id` join
     `tags` t
     ON t.`id` = p.`id`
group by p.id
having sum(t.`type` = 'caseMaterial' AND t.name = 'leather') > 0 and
       sum(t.`type` = 'caseFor' AND t.`name` = 'iphone-5') > 0;
```

However, I'm not quite sure how this relates to the tables at the beginning of the question.  Your code sample and data layout are not consistent.

Comment: This didn't work, I had to change the line: ON t.`id` = p.`id` to ON t.`id` = pt.`tag_id`.
But thank you!!! The first piece of the puzzle is solved

Answer (score 0):

I extended the solution of @Gordon Linoff by adding the category join.

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM `products` p join 
     `categories` c
     ON c.`id` = p.`category_id` join
     `product_tag` pt
     ON pt.`product_id` = p.`id` join
     `tags` t
     ON t.`id` = pt.`tag_id`
where c.id = 1
group by p.id
having sum(t.`type` = 'phoneType' AND t.name = 'smart-phone') > 0 and
       sum(t.`type` = 'phoneColor' AND t.`name` = 'red') > 0
```

This is working now. Thanks to @Gordon Linoff.